# Laravel Queue start a second job after first job

Tags: laravel, queue

In my Laravel 5.1 project I want to start my second job when first will finished.

Here is my logic.

```
\Queue::push(new MyJob())
```

and when this job finish I want to start this job

```
\Queue::push(new ClearJob())
```

How can i realize this?

Comment: Not 100% sure this is the best solution, but I am aware of the **job events** feature: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-events. You could start the `ClearJob` in the `Queue::after()` method for `MyJob`.

Comment: Why not just dispatch the second job at the end of the first job? `$this->dispatch(new ClearJob());` you will need to make sure the Job has the `DispatchesJobs` trait also.

Comment: where I need to use . it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this, you just should define 1 `Queue`.

> A queue is just a list/line of things waiting to be handled in order,
>   starting from the beginning. When I say things, I mean jobs. - https://toniperic.com/2015/12/01/laravel-queues-demystified

To get the opposite of what you want: async executed Jobs, you should define a new `Queue` for every `Job`.

### Multiple Queues and Workers

> You can have different queues/lists for
>   storing the jobs. You can name them however you want, such as “images”
>   for pushing image processing tasks, or “emails” for queue that holds
>   jobs specific to sending emails. You can also have multiple workers,
>   each working on a different queue if you want. You can even have
>   multiple workers per queue, thus having more than one job being worked
>   on simultaneously. Bear in mind having multiple workers comes with a
>   CPU and memory cost. Look it up in the official docs, it’s pretty
>   straightforward.